# Regex to match all URLs that follow after several different sub-directory paths

Tags: regex

I need a regEx that targets all of the product pages and any other products not shown in this example but that are in the same directory level as the products in this example:

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/category-a/view-all/product-a.html
http://www.example.com/category-b/view-all/product-g.html
http://www.example.com/category-c-c/view-all/product-y.html
http://www.example.com/category-d/view-all/product-h.html
```

Comment: could possibly use some more info but perhaps this may work for you `/\/category[^\/]*/view-all\//` (outer `/` as regex/pattern delim)

Comment: What have you tried? Your title's misleading if your example is a good sampling of your data. None of those URLs have different sub-domains

Comment: The example with a different sub domain is missing

Comment: Apologies I ment sub-directories not sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JavaScript Example:

```
/http:\/\/www.example.com\/[^\/]+\/view-all\/.+/i
```

Comment: Hi this didn't work for me. I'm using the code inside of the testing software Optimizely to highly a pageview on any of these product pages as the goal of my test.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex below will match the top level and all pages named product on that directory.

```
http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/category.*view-all\/product.*\.html
```

Comment: the word product does not feature in the urls. It's the individual product names that would be showing. i.e. no pattern as they are all different.